# Opening checkout page in new tab at the end of Woocommerce payment

Tags: wordpress

We have a donation site project. donation plugin I use is "Donation Platform for WooCommerce: Fundraising & Donation Management"
Since the broadcast stream will continue on the site, when the "Donate Now" button is clicked, the checkout page must be opened in a new tab without disturbing the broadcast flow.
Is there a way to open the checkout page in a new tab? Or is there another method you recommend?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIRLs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `formtarget="_blank"` attribute in button element to open in new window without disturbing the broadcast flow.

Comment: I don't know where to add the formtarget="_blank" code. I am giving the links of the plugins I use.

Donation Platform for WooCommerce: Fundraising & Donation Management

WooCommerce

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).